# How can i store image data from matrix<float> to Image<gray,float> object?

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv

Also i want to ask when we convert any image to grayscale does it have two channels(gray and alpha) or one (gray only)?

I want to store image data from 2 channeled matrix(float) object to Image(gray,float) object. what is the easiest way? Thanks.